# Google Groups Migration API not permitting any API Requests

Tags: google-api, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm having trouble getting the Google Groups Migration API to work properly.  I can get access to the API, but I can't do anything once I have access.

In the [developer playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), under the Select & Authorize APIs heading, I add this custom scope into the input field:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.migration`

This is the scope is listed in [Google's docutmention](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/guides/authorizing), so I'm pretty sure it's correct.

I consent to OAuth access for the developer playground and then in Step 2, I'm able to exchange an access token for tokens.

The problem is that on Step 3, when I press the button marked "list possible operations," it tells me there are no available operations.

To summarize, I'm able to get an access token for the Google Groups Migration API, but I'm not allowed to perform any actions.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all APIs list possible operations so you need to configure the operation manually. Based on the Groups Migration [archive.insert()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/reference/archive/insert) reference, you need to:

1. Set HTTP Method to "POST"
2. Change Content Type to Custom, "message/rfc822"
3. Set the Request URI to "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/GROUPEMAIL/archive?uploadType=media" (replace GROUPEMAIL with groups actual address)
4. Enter a body request of a sample message like the one below (make sure you have all needed headers like from, to, subject, message-id, etc).

`Received: by 10.143.160.15 with HTTP; Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: 
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700
From: "samplesender@example.com"
To: "samplegroup@googlegroups.com"
Subject: SUBJECT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline
Delivered-To: samplegroup@samplegroup.com`

This is the body of the migrated email message.

once you have all those elements, sending the request should succeed and you should see the message in the group archive.

Note that the API only works for Google Groups for Business. You must authenticate as a Google Apps Super Admin user and be POSTing to a Google Groups for Business group (doesn't end in @googlegroups.com). These requirements are [spelled out in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/guides/prerequisites).